# A power Diophantine equation $(p+q)^n-p^n-q^n+1=m^{p-q}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Suppose $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers, $n>1$ and $m>1$ are positive integers. Solve the following Diophantine equation:$$(p+q)^n-p^n-q^n+1=m^{p-q}$$I made this problem and I was trying to find $p$ and $q$ first. Looking mod $p$, $q$ and $p+q$ gives$$m^{p-q} \equiv 1 \pmod {pq(p+q)}$$Does this provide useful information about $p$ and $q$?

Comment: If $p,q$ are odd primes, then the L.H.S. is a square, and that fact by itself should restrict the number of solutions.

Comment: $(5+3)^3-5^3-3^3+1=361=19^{(5-3)}$

Comment: Actually I think that's the only solution for $p>3$.

Comment: I was only able to show $\min(p,q)\le3$, by using this fact every prime number greater than three has the form $6k\pm1$ and using modular $4$. Does this do any help?

Comment: Obviously $m$ is odd. So for $p>3$ and $q>3$, R.H.S. is $1 \pmod 4$, but I can't conclude that L.H.S. is not $1 \pmod 4$ always.

Comment: Oh, right. I did a little mistake on my conclusion, sorry.

Comment: Perhaps a little obvious, but still worth mentioning explicitly I think: If $p=3$ and $q=2$ then for every $n>1$ there is the solution 
$$m=(p+q)^n-p^n-q^n+1.$$

Comment: @Garthal What makes you think that is the only solution for $p>3$? I've been struggling to make progress on this question...

Comment: That's right. We get a family of solution from here.

Comment: @Servaes I made a computer search and there was nothing except that one for relatively high values. That's a conjecture.

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/240092/a-power-diophantine-equation-involving-primes with no acknowledgement of the post here.

Comment: I don't understand why the Edit 1 is true, after all $n$ can be even.

Comment: Note that $p^q+q^q=(p+q)(p^{q-1}-p^{q-2}q+\dots)$. Actually I give up on original version. I'm going to add an important edit, which proves $p-q=2(2l+1)$ for easier version.

Comment: How do you get $n^{p-2}=4p+1$ if $q=2$?

Comment: And as I noted before, there are infinitely many solutions for $p=3$, $q=2$, so your Edit 3 is false.

Comment: How do you suddenly get $n=q$ and $m=n$?

Comment: I changed the equation to an easier version. I removed $m$ in the new equation. See Edit 2.